# git communication over http

Tags: git, http, request

I want to have git commands (.i.e git clone, git push, ...) in http request format. without using git library. I dont want to use (for example) gitlab api for this type of requests.
Request should be something like this (from this [link](https://mincong.io/2018/05/04/git-and-http/)):

```
GET http://root@localhost/root/app.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

This will retuen something like this (branches)

```
001e# service=git-upload-pack\n
000000fafac36d407e123c2499149fcc8c1fc8ebe5ecd301 HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.11.1
003ffac36d407e123c2499149fcc8c1fc8ebe5ecd301 refs/heads/master
0000
```

I couldnt find an appropriate doc or example for this job. It seems that a git request consist of multiple send/receive operation.

In summary I want to know how should I implement git operations in http request format.

Tnx

Comment: Looks like the docs are here: https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're going to want to use a Git library for this unless you're planning to write your own.  Here's why:

Git supports two types of HTTP remotes: the DAV-based (dumb) protocol and the smart protocol.  In addition, the smart protocol also supports protocols 0 and 1 (which are nearly identical) and protocol 2, which is quite different.  So to implement this in a meaningful way, you're going to have to implement a lot of functionality.

In addition, the smart protocol performs negotiation of what data is present on both sides and sends only the data that differs.  In such a case, you necessarily have to walk the history of the repository to determine what objects are common, which means you will also need to read loose and packed objects, read and write references, and fill out the missing objects in thin packs.  All of these require basic Git primitives.

If you still want to do it nevertheless, you should look in the `Documentation/technical` directory in the Git source code at the `http-protocol.txt` and `pack-protocol.txt` files, plus the files starting with `protocol-`.